# Create yaml template to create group and passing the users via list in openshift / kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, openshift

I need to add several users to a new group template

```
apiVersion: template.openshift.io/v1
kind: Template
metadata:
  name: group-devops-template
objects:
- apiVersion: user.openshift.io/v1
  kind: Group
  metadata:
    name: ${GROUP_NAME}
  users: ["${USER_NAMES}"] # <--- here the issue
  #- user1
  #- user2
  #- user3
parameters:
- name: GROUP_NAME
  description: Password used for Redis authentication

- name: USER_NAMES
  description: user or users to add
```

The nightmare happens when I process the template with the values.

```
oc process -f grup_template3 -p GROUP_NAME=admin_devops  -p USER_NAMES=["user1","user2","user3"]  | oc create -f -
```

### And here my questions:

- How to specify the list correctly in the above template
- How to specify correctly the list of values: ["user1","user2","user3"]

#### The final group with the desired users should like this:

```
oc get groups admin_devops -o yaml
```

```
apiVersion: user.openshift.io/v1
kind: Group
metadata:
  name: admin_devops
users:
- user1
- user2
- user3
```

Any idea about how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Your users var should be written as `${{USER_NAMES}` and `USER_NAMES` var should be formatted as a correct yaml. Here is working example:

**template.yaml**

```yaml
apiVersion: template.openshift.io/v1
kind: Template
metadata:
  name: group-devops-template
objects:
- apiVersion: user.openshift.io/v1
  kind: Group
  metadata:
    name: ${GROUP_NAME}
  users: ${{USER_NAMES}}
parameters:
- name: GROUP_NAME
  description: Password used for Redis authentication
- name: USER_NAMES
  description: user or users to add
```

**command:**

```
oc process -f template.yaml -p GROUP_NAME=admin_devops  -p USER_NAMES='["user1","user2","user3"]' --local=true -o yaml
```

**output:**

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
items:
- apiVersion: user.openshift.io/v1
  kind: Group
  metadata:
    name: admin_devops
  users:
  - user1
  - user2
  - user3
kind: List
metadata: {}
```

Comment: great thanks for this!